# Error in compiling using bibtex

Tags: bibtex

When compiling the following try19A.tex file I get the following error as message:

```
Could not start Recompile Bibliography:PdfLatex:
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "try19A".tex
```

The file try19A.tex is:

```
\usepackage{filecontents}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{abstract}
 \end{abstract}
 \section{Introduction}
 \newpage
 \bibliography{TRY19}{}
 \bibliographystyle{plain}
 \nocite*

 \end{document}
```

Where the file TRY19.bib is:

```
@article{kargupta2004fourier,
  title={A fourier spectrum-based approach to represent decision trees for mining data streams in mobile environments},
  author={Kargupta, Hillol and Park, Byung-Hoon},
  journal={Knowledge and Data Engineering, IEEE Transactions on},
  volume={16},
  number={2},
  pages={216--229},
  year={2004},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
@article{mukherjee2006privacy,
  title={A privacy-preserving technique for Euclidean distance-based mining algorithms using Fourier-related transforms},
  author={Mukherjee, Shibnath and Chen, Zhiyuan and Gangopadhyay, Aryya},
  journal={The VLDB Journal—The International Journal on Very Large Data Bases},
  volume={15},
  number={4},
  pages={293--315},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Springer-Verlag New York, Inc.}
}
```

Comment: you are asking a lot of similar questions, i posted a working document earlier today, why are you using the above example (which is missing a `\documentclass` line? However that does not account for pdflatex not starting, does it work with any file (is pdflatex installed)

Comment: How can I know if pdflatex is installed?

Comment: well, have you installed it? You are asking about bibtex but have you run latex on a simpler document that does not use bibtex and just has `hello world` ?

Comment: Yes, sure all my paper with tables, graph, algorithms etc, works perfect just the bibliography has problems...

Comment: the document you posted above will produce the error  `! LaTeX Error: \usepackage before \documentclass.` as it has no `\documentclass` but this question (again) seems to be a duplicate of your first question really

Comment: If you save the file that I posted before as file.tex and do `pdflatex file` then `bibtex file` then `pdflatex file` you will get the typeset bibliography as shown in the image in my answer.